# MSSQL 2012 - How to combine multiple rows and columns into single row

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

My records are look like below:

[image]

I want to combine all multiple rows and columns into single row as:

109,0,0|123,1,1|174,0,0|321,0,0........

Each row combined will separate with a pipe and there no pipe separator for the last row.

Currently I'm using MSSQL 2012. Any help are much appreciate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a method with xml:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE
    (
      idno INT ,
     idfound INT, 
     pofound int
    )
INSERT  INTO @t VALUES
(109, 0, 0),
(123, 1, 1),
(174, 0, 0),
(321, 0, 0),
(456, 0, 1),
(509, 0, 0),
(654, 0, 1),
(687, 0, 1),
(789, 0, 0),
(987, 0, 0)

;WITH cte AS(SELECT CAST(idno AS VARCHAR(max)) + ',' + 
                    CAST(idfound AS VARCHAR(max)) + ',' + 
                    CAST(pofound AS VARCHAR(max)) AS col FROM @t)
SELECT STUFF((SELECT '|' + col FROM cte
              FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '')
```

Output:

```
109,0,0|123,1,1|174,0,0|321,0,0|456,0,1|509,0,0|654,0,1|687,0,1|789,0,0|987,0,0
```

Comment: I was writing something using a cursor - this is much cleaner and gets my upvote.

Comment: Thank Giorgi, output as expected.

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @Result VARCHAR(MAX) --To store the result

SELECT
    @Result = CONCAT(@Result+'|',CONCAT(idno,',',idfound,',',pofound))
FROM YourTable


SELECT @Result
```

Here I used the `@Result+'|'` in the code to avoid adding pipe before the first row data

### Output

```
109,0,0|123,1,1|174,0,0|321,0,0|456,0,1|509,0,0|654,0,1|687,0,1|789,0,0|987,0,0
```

### Note

`CONCAT` treats `NULL` value as Empty string where as '`+`' operator wont, that is because i used both in the query